# How to programmatically start and stop apache pulsar consumer?

Tags: apache-pulsar

Is there any way you can programmatically control to start/stop apache consumer?

There are pause and resume but looks like it is not working as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messages received from the broker are buffered in the consumer `receiverQueue`. The `pause` method of the consumer will make it stop asking for more messages from the broker. So the messages you get are probably the ones buffered into the receiverQueue. From your application perspective, you'll stop receiving messages once the receiver queue is drained.

Comment: Is that a "receiverQueueSize" or "maxTotalReceiverQueueSizeAcrossPartitions" property controls this behavior?

Comment: Both if the topic is partitioned. The code is `int receiverQueueSize = Math.min(conf.getReceiverQueueSize(), conf.getMaxTotalReceiverQueueSizeAcrossPartitions() / numPartitions);`